# Howto make an HTML box with shadow and pressable

Tags: html, box-shadow

I would like to make an HTML widget like this one:
https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/

```
.simple {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

But I would like it to be pressable so that it flattens for 1 second and redirects to a different URL.

**Edit:**

I tried the following:

```
button {
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 2;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #777, #ddd);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

button:focus, button:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #888, #eee);
}

button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 1px black,
              inset 2px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
              inset -2px -3px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

<button>Press me!</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z7a0v8uv/

But I don't know how to translate the content of the button to make it look like it's being pressed down.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an answer here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_animate_buttons.asp

I was looking for:

```
translateX(...) translateY(...)
```

As we can see in this working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/z7a0v8uv/1/

Now I just need to integrate this with the right style.

**Edit:**

Here is the complete CSS code:

```
button {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

button:focus, button:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #888, #eee);
}

button:active {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  transform: translateY(3px) translateX(3px);
}
```

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. You must post the code that answers the question here, not a third party site or links to other pages that will change or disappear helping no one in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer